# Low FG due to cacao nibs?

Tags: stout, final-gravity, chocolate

I recently brewed an oatmeal cream stout from the Mashmaker book (recipe here https://growlermag.com/homebrew-recipe-oatmeal-cream-double-stout/) with the intention of adding some chocolate & hazelnut flavours.

Main difference initially is that I added some cacao nibs to the mash.

I hit the OG, however the FG has come out at 1.032, rather than the expected ~1.015...

I had read the yeast I was using is highly flocculant, so I pitched some more after 2 weeks, to no avail. Fermentation schedule looked like -

- Day 0 - 18C, pitched 1 smackpack 1318 London 3 yeast
- Day 6 - 21C, roused yeast, gravity 1.032
- Day 13 - 21C, still 1.032, added 1 pack dry Garvin/Nottingham yeast
- Day 17 - still 1.032

For completeness, I scaled this down to an 11L brew:

- Maris otter   2240g
- Flaked Oats   263g
- Roasted malt (blackprinz) 230g
- Pale Chocolate    209g
- Crystal 120 (Dark Crystal)    164g
- Lactose   263g
- Nugget @ 60min    16g
- Cacao nibs (mash) 49g
- Cacao nibs (secondary)    98g

Any thoughts on what might have gone wrong here - could the cacao nibs have somehow impacted the amount of fermentable sugers in the mash? (or are my sums just off..?)

Comment: what was your mash temp? I had something similar, and had mashed way to high and ended aith 1.040 F.G.

Comment: Mashed at 68C, for 90mins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. I'm not aware of cacao nibs having any enzyme inhibiting abilities.

Either something else caused a less fermentable wort. Ie higher temp or low beta-amylase in malt.

Or, something caused yeast to give up on an otherwise fermentable wort.  Stress, low nutrients, low oxygen, low pitch etc.

Edit: looking closer at the recipe I would NOT put a 1.015 target on it. Much closer to 1.030. **I believe you are at terminal gravity with 1.032**. About 50-75% of your sugars from the specialty grains will not ferment. 100% of the Lactos will not ferment.

Comment: Thanks! So it's pretty unlikely this recipe would have hit 7 or 8% regardless? The FG there I calculated based on the OG and expected final ABV.

Comment: Only a prgram like beersmith will properly guess a FG and take into concideration unfermentable sugars based on mash process, grain type, sugar type.